# excel macro find a specific string and copy PART of it to another cell

Tags: excel, vba

can anyone help me with this
excel macro find a specific string and copy PART of it to another cell

i found this macro, but it copies the whole column. i only want part info from the column

```
Sub Luxation2()
    Dim K As Long, r As Range, v As Variant
    K = 1
    Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
    Set w1 = Sheets("Sections")
    Set w2 = Sheets("retry")
    w1.Activate
    For Each r In Intersect(Range("B:B"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        v = r.Value
        If InStr(v, "periode") > 0 Then
            r.Copy w2.Cells(K, 1)
            K = K + 1
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Show what you have so far.

Comment: What part do you want to copy?

Comment: I just tested this and it works as expected, not as descibed.

Comment: in sheet Sections there is a column with text: hello - world - today"
i only want the text between the two colons (-). in this case "world"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently bored and killing time, so here you go.

```
Sub Luxation2()
    Dim K As Long, r As Range, v As Variant, p As Long, q As Long
    K = 1
    Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
    Set w1 = Sheets("Sections")
    Set w2 = Sheets("retry")
    For Each r In Intersect(w1.Range("B:B"), w1.UsedRange)
        v = r.Value
        p = InStr(1, v, " - ")
        q = InStrRev(v, " - ")
        w2.Cells(K, 1) = Mid(v, p + 3, q - p - 3)
        K = K + 1
    Next r
End Sub
```

The code makes all sorts of assumptions.  All used cells in column B of the "Sections" worksheet must be in the "hello - world - today" format you specified in your comment above.  It will error if it encounters any blank cells or cells not in that format.